# Javascript random function does not work as intended

Tags: javascript

I got the following random function from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp):

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    var intMin = parseInt(min);
    var intMax = parseInt(max);

    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * intMax) + intMin);
}
```

if i now set the following for example:

```
var min = 1;
var max = 5;

var random = getRandomInt(min, max);
```

I get correct number between 1 and 5.
If i set the following:

```
var min = 2;
var max = 6;

var random = getRandomInt(min, max);
```

i sometimes also get the number 7. If min is 3 and max i 6 i also sometimes get the 8. So how can i get random numbers between a [min, max] if even the example from w3schools doesnt work?

Comment: Avoid w3schools. You've misunderstood parts of their examples because of how poorly written they are. - See: http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is just wrong. Here's a fixed one:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    var intMin = parseInt(min);
    var intMax = parseInt(max);
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (intMax-intMin)) + intMin);
}
```

Unless you really want to pass strings as input, it's ridiculous to always parse them. Prefer this version for normal use:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min)) + min);
}
```

As with all random functions, this never produces the max, but a result in `[min,max[`. If you want to get a result in `[min,max]` (without bias), return `(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max+1-min)) + min)`.

And last thing. Avoid this w3schools site. There are too many errors and missing precision on this site.

Comment: this is also wrong. if you put min = 2 and max = 6, the 6 never appears after 10000 runs.

Comment: @Mulgard This is intended. The random is inclusive.

Comment: maybe but that is not what i want. i want max to be included

Comment: Agree with that, avoid w3schools! Always use MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: yes with that everything works fine. and i put in strings only so i need the parseInt before.

Answer (score 0):

I've a very good solution. Please check out this [Gist from KnightCoder](https://gist.github.com/KnightCoder/a6163688a35c96da0663)

```
if (!Math.prototype.getRandomValueBetween) {
    Math.prototype.getRandomValueBetween = function (from, to) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
    };
}
//USAGE -- Math.getRandomValueBetween(100,1000) //950
```

Its very cool optimized code snippet. You can also check out the entire list of his gists [here](https://gist.github.com/KnightCoder)

If you find this answer better or correct please mark this as correct or at least useful. 
Thanks :)